# Register MouseListener and MouseMotionListener simultaneously

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, mouselistener, mousemotionlistener

I am trying to write a `Mouse` class (implementing `MouseListener` and `MouseMotionListener`) containing `mousePressed()` and `mouseMoved()`. I want to be able to detect mouse motion while the mouse is down. I can detect each separately, but not at the same time. For example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Test extends JPanel {
  public Test() {
     Mouse m = new Mouse();
     addMouseListener(m);
     addMouseMotionListener(m);
  }
  class Mouse implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{
     public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Pressed");
     }
     public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Moved");
     }
     public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {}
     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
     public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
     public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
     public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     JFrame frame = new JFrame();
     frame.setSize(500, 500);
     frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.setContentPane(new Test());
     frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

As you should see, "Pressed" and "Moved" are both printed out, but once the mouse is pressed, "Moved" is not printed until the mouse is released. How would I make it so that it would do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the Java API:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html)

> void   mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
>
> Invoked when a mouse button is pressed on a component and then dragged.
>
> void   mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
>
> Invoked when the mouse cursor has been moved onto a component but no buttons have been pushed.

`mouseMoved` events are only fired when no buttons are pressed.

Comment: @RobotKarel314 I've been writing Java code for nearly a decade and I still bring up the relevant API pages every time I start working on something new.  Learn to love the documentation.  It's surprisingly easy to read, and often links to examples.

Answer (score 2):

> As you should see, "Pressed" and "Moved" are both printed out, but once the mouse is pressed, "Moved" is not printed until the mouse is released.

When the mouse is pressed the event you need to handle is the `mouseDragged` event.

Comment: Gee, I helped you on several question in the past and  I answered the question first and I didn't even get a thank you. Good luck on your future questions.